# Create and populate HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<object>>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have an assignment for school that's all about using files, HashMap and ArrayList. This assignment requires 4 classes.

The first class is called FileReader and reads a txt file which is written line by line and each field that we need is separated by ";", for example ("Columbia University";"USA";78.86;2012). Each line contains 2 strings (university name and country) and 2 numbers (score and year). The FileReader class after reading the txt file returns its content in an arraylist.

The second class of the assignment is called UniversityScores and it has 4 fields (uniname, country, score, year), a constructor, accessor methods for all fields and a toString method.

The third class is the heart of our program. This class is called FileEditor and creates a Hashmap<Integer,ArrayList<UniversityScores>> where the key is the **year** field of each object and value I guess is the rest of the line. My problem is filling the right way the HashMap.

Also, my final 4th class is called FileWriter which creates a new txt and writes inside of it. All my classes work as supposed to except my FileEditor class. Any help needed. Thank you in advance!

Edit 
I am supposed to write some other methods as well. For now my problem is the FileEditor class. I also posted the TestFiles class which contains the main function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class FileReader{

private String fileName;
private Scanner scanner;
private File file;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private String line;

public FileReader(String otherFileName){
    this.fileName = otherFileName;
    this.file = new File(fileName);
}

public boolean initReader(){
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Just caught a FileNotFoundException.");
    }

    if(file.exists()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> readFile(){
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        this.line = scanner.nextLine();
        arrayList.add(line);
    }
    arrayList.remove(0);
    //System.out.println(arrayList);
    return arrayList;
}

public void closeReader(){
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("Scanner closed");
}
}
```

‌

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class FileWriter{

private String path;
private PrintWriter writer;
private File outputFile;

public FileWriter(String otherPath){
    this.path = otherPath;
    this.outputFile = new File(path);
}

public boolean initWriter(){
    try{
        writer = new PrintWriter(path);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("just caught an exception");
    }

    if(outputFile.exists()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }   
}

public void writeFile(){
    writer.println("The first line");
    writer.println("The second line");
    writer.println("Christos");
}

public void closeWriter(){
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("Writer closed");
}
}
```

‌

```
class UniversityScore{

private String name;
private String country;
private double score;
private int year;

public UniversityScore(String otherName, String otherCountry, double otherScore, int otherYear){
    this.name = otherName;
    this.country = otherCountry;
    this.score = otherScore;
    this.year = otherYear;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getCountry(){
    return country;
}

public double getScore(){
    return score;
}

public int getYear(){
    return year;
}

public String toString(){
    String outputString = name + "\t" + country + "\t" + score + "\t" + year;
    return outputString;
}
}
```

‌

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class FileEditor{

private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<UniversityScore>> scores = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<UniversityScore>>();
private ArrayList<String> lines;

public FileEditor(ArrayList<String> otherLines){
    this.lines = otherLines;
}

public void fillHashMap(){
   // that's where I need help
}
```

}

```
public class TestFiles {
public static void main(String[] args){
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("universities.txt");
    if(reader.initReader()){
        FileEditor editor = new FileEditor(reader.readFile());
        reader.closeReader();
        editor.fillHashMap();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("universities_2015_output.txt");
        if(writer.initWriter()){
            writer.writeFile(editor.getScoresOfYear(2015));
            writer.closeWriter();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error creating file");
        }
        System.out.println("Average university score of year 2015: "+editor.getAverageOfYear(2015));
        System.out.println("Min university score of year 2015: "+editor.getMinOfYear(2015));
        System.out.println("Max university score of year 2015: "+editor.getMaxOfYear(2015));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your _specific_ programming question?

Comment: I don't understand how I am going to fill the hashmap with the right keys and values.

Comment: You don't show the FileEditor class.  What have you tried already that isn't working?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't upload the FileEditor class because all I was able to do is just defining the HashMap. Just uploaded!

Comment: Are you saying you don’t know what methods exist in the HashMap class?  Did you read its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Comment: I have read the HashMap documentation, however in this specific case I don't know how to write the FileEditor class in order to create the HashMap I need. The fillHashMap method is supposed to fill the hashmap in the right order that is presented in the lines arraylist. I need a HashMap with a key that is equal to the year field of UniversityScores objects for each object in the arraylist and as value I need the rest of each line of the txt file.

Comment: Lets say the key is your Univeristy Score and values are list of University that has same score. Then you need to check If there are any list ( in values of your map) for your key that you are about to add. If yes, then you need to fetch the values List, add your univeristy to that list and put back in map . If no, you just add new List with your univeristy in it to your map.

Comment: Then first create a `List<UniversityScore>` from `lines`. Then iterate through that list, put elements in your Map

Comment: This is an example of my input file: "Columbia University";"USA";78.86;2012 as I already said in my UniversityScores class I have 4 private fields, name = Columbia University, country = USA, score = 78.86 and year = 2012. I need to create a HashMap where the year field of each UniversityScores object is the key and the rest of the fields is the value. Somehow I need to separate these fields between the " ; " and then create the HashMap. Please if you found a solution post it as an answer with the code written in order to be more accurate! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a way to parse your lines into `UniversityScore` objects.

Now that you have all the scores, you can add it to your map, according to their year values (may be score but the type doesn't match nor makes practical sense), for example:

```
for(String line : lines){
      String[] vals = line.split(";");
      UniversityScore score = new UniversityScore(vals[0],vals[1],Double.parseDouble(vals[2]),Integer.parseInt(vals[3]))
      if(scores.containsKey(score.getYear()){ // If the key exists
         scores.get(score.getYear()).add(score);
      }else{ // If the key doesn't exist, it must be created and added to the map
         ArrayList<UniversityScore> newList = new ArrayList<>();
         newList.add(score);
         scores.put(score.getYear(), newList)
      }
    }
```

I noticed your map has an `Integer` key which corresponds to the `year` property of a score, so I assumed the map's keys are the years and not the scores as you suggested.

I didn't check if the code works, but it should at least give you an idea on how to fill your map.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at FileEditor.fillHashMap(FileEditor.java:17)
        at TestFiles.main(TestFiles.java:27)

Comment: Check the split function. And the line that is split. It seems the line only contains two values instead of 4? You can do that by printing the line and the length of the vals array. Adapt your code to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're being tasked with reading data from a file, and then generating some stats about the data in the file.

Currently, you're simply plopping each line in the ArrayList.

Looks like your next step is to go through each item in that list, and create a UniversityScore object. This is where you will have to parse each string into values that can be assigned to the various fields in the UniversityScore object. When you have done that, put the current line number (as an Integer key) and UniversityScore (as the value) in your HashMap.

Once you have done that, you will have to write the missing methods getScoresOfYear(Integer year), getAverageOfYear(int year), getMinOfYear(int year), and getMaxOfYear(int year) in the editor class.

Comment: Great, finally someone that understands what I need. Could you please help me with the code of the next step you are telling me about?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
public void fillHashMap() {
    for(String line : lines) {
        String [] fields = line.split(";");
        UniversityScores us = new UniversityScores(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);

       if (scores.keySet().contains(us.getScore())) {
           scores.get(us.getScore()).add(us);
       }
       else {
           ArrayList<UniversityScores> t = new ArrayList<UniversityScores>();
           t.add(us);
           scores.put(us.getScore(), t);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: I get an error. FileEditor.java:17: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double
                        UniversityScore us = new UniversityScore(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);

Comment: That's a different question.  Your constructor is expecting a double, and fields[2] and/or fields[3] is a string.  You need to handle that...

Comment: My constructor is written as it's supposed to be. How can we change your answer code in order to get what we need?

Comment: As Theo's answer shows, call `parseDouble(fields[2])` and `parseInt(fields[3])` as appropriate.  You are supposed to be contributing to your own learning.  Do you really want everything spoon fed to you on a silver platter?

Comment: Well, you are right, Theo's solution actually works but now the problem is that my file is 2200 lines and I get an error of  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2. However when I compile and run the program with a file of 10 lines it runs perfectly. What am I doing wrong?? Also it's my first time working on collections which means that I don't understand certain things so please excuse me about that.

Comment: There are several ways to find the issue. Theo's comment is correct.  At some point in that 2200 line file some line doesn't have 4 fields, it only has 2 because your code hit the index OB exception at the third field (index 2) on that line.  Put in a line counting debug statement like `System.out.println("processing line " + i++)` (where `int i = 0;` is declared before your for loop) and see where it dies.  Then you need to figure out if the file is bad and needs fixing or if you are supposed to handle that "bad data" possibility in your code.